# Suggested Article is not showing in my cases

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, case, administration, knowledge

I have dropped the knowledge search in my cases page through Lighting App builder but in my suggested article section. Articles are not showing can you please suggest some solution for showing the articles. I have shown the problem through the below image

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue even if Knowledge setting is configured. Also enabled the suggested articles on Case on the basis of Subject field. Did you find any solution why suggested articles are not showing?

Answer (score 0):

To enable suggested articles:

- From Setup, enter Support Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Support Settings.
- Click Edit and choose Enable suggested articles. Suggested articles and suggested solutions cannot be enabled at the same time.
- Choose each audience (channel) that receives suggested articles when submitting a case. Suggested articles are available for the internal app and the portals.
- When you're done with the Support Settings page click Save.

Go through the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_suggest_articles.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I have already Enable the suggested articles .but still it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

If after completing Hariprasath steps the articles are still not showing, I would suggest go to Setup enter Knowledge Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Knowledge Settings, click Edit, and check which Case fields are being used to filter the Suggestion Articles. After that, in your Case, double check that the field has any key word related to the article!
[image]